# Generate new List<string> based on substring match in List<string> in c#

Tags: c#, list, substring

Consider a c# `List<string> files` with the following content

```
C:\z1\z1.docx
C:\z1\z2.docx
C:\z2\z2.docx    // <--- file z2.docx has the same name as in folder z1.
```

I now want to find all files with the same *filename* and receive back a list which contains the *full path + filename*

`List<string> duplicates`

```
C:\z1\z2.docx
C:\z2\z2.docx
```

I'm asking, since it is easy to code a solution with loops and other inefficent ways, but I want to use an elegant solution and my knowlege of List-operations in c# is not sufficient.

Comment: Make use of `LINQ`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you thing loops would be inefficient - that's what LINQ will do under the covers anyway. But if you want to use LINQ you can achieve that using a couple of method calls:

```
var result = files.GroupBy(p => Path.GetFileName(p))
                  .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                  .SelectMany(g => g);
```

It will group by the filename first, discard all the groups with only 1 element and flatten the remaining groups into a single collection of paths.

You can add a `ToList` call after `SelectMany` to materialize results into a `List<string>`.

Comment: Downvoters care to comment? It returns exactly what OP expects based on sample input/output.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<string> duplicates = new List<string>() { @"C:\z1\z1.docx",
                                            @"C:\z1\z2.docx", @"C:\z2\z2.docx" };
        List<dynamic> GetList(List<string> FilesToCheck)
        {
            var Files = from file in FilesToCheck
                        where duplicates.Contains(file)
                        select new { FileName = new FileInfo(file).Name, FullName      
                        = new FileInfo(file).FullName };
            return Files.ToList();
        }
```

Comment: `where duplicates.Contains(file)` will always be true, because `file` is taken from `duplicates` to begin with.

Comment: It will be true for files contained in the provided list. This is what he asked for and is elegant as well. Your solution is good also.

Comment: Sorry, but I think you misunderstood me. It will **always** be true, because you're iterating over elements in a list and later on check if that element is present **in the same** list.  You just took it form the list, so it has to be there ...